# Implementations on AdMob (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, admob, ads

How going, dudes?
So today it's a really ridiculous question, but i just can't get it to work the way i want.
I'm implementing the AdMob stuff but i want to get some additional information.

They gave the instructions on the [GoogleCodes/AdMob](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/intermediate.html)
but i can't make it give me the logs i want.

This is on the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"

@interface AppForAllTestsViewController : UIViewController<GADBannerViewDelegate>
```

This is on the .m

```
-(void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView{
    NSLog(@"RECEIVED");

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"BannerSlide" context:nil];
    bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - bannerView.frame.size.height, 
                                   bannerView.frame.size.width, 
                                   bannerView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error{
    NSLog(@"FAILURE RECEIVING AD: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


-(void)adMobProcess{
    adMobBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 
                                                                 self.view.frame.size.height-GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, 
                                                                 GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, 
                                                                 GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    adMobBanner.adUnitID = my_id;
    adMobBanner.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:adMobBanner];
    [adMobBanner loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

}

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    NSLog(@"GOOD MORNING");
    [adMobBanner setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self adMobProcess];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

You can see that i'm setting the delegate to "self" but nothing happens, none of the changes, can any one, please, help me? (:

Comment: Could you update your code with what works please?  Not so sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AdMob [iOS documentation](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/intermediate.html#gadbannerviewdelegate) states:

> Remember to set the delegate using the setDelegate: before making the request for an ad.

Because you set the delegate in awakeFromNib, you are either setting the delegate before initializing the adMobBanner (NPE?), or you are setting it after the adRequest.  You should instead set the delegate in adMobProcess before calling loadRequest.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Google Admob Library https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadios

Except the Add-ons and readme.txt file drag the all file to your project

Build Settings -> Search path -> Library Search Path and Header Search Path add the Google Admob File Link as **RECURSIVE** $(SRCROOT)/Folder_Name Folder_Name Specifies where the Library Placed

Dont Use self.view.frame.size.height for iPhone and iPad this differs the banner height...

Use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height this will automatically identify the iPhone and iPad display Screen Bounds

Adjust the Height place the banner in Correct Position

adViewDidReceiveAd its a delegate method so in .h file u must call the delegate method

```
<GADBannerViewDelegate>

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {

        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                          [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 150,
                                          GAD_SIZE_728x90.width + 50,
                                          GAD_SIZE_728x90.height)];

    }

    else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {

        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                       [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 113,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    }


    // Specify the ad unit ID.

    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"****************";

    [bannerView_ setDelegate:self];

    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view

{

    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to set the frame when initializing the banner view in order for it to make use of the delegate.

```
// Delegate methods NOT CALLED
self.bannerView = [[DFPBannerView alloc] init];

// Delegate methods ARE CALLED
self.bannerView = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
```